# MIPS : Printing n time a number in a file

Tags: mips

I'm currently working on a project for school. I'm asked to generate a random list of number in a text file, and first of all I tried to print n times a number in a test file, 31 for example. However, no matter the value of n, I always get my test.txt file with "31 " printed in but only one time. Here's my code (I'm a beginner btw) :

```
.data     

question:    .asciiz   "\nEnter a number : ?\n"
mynumber: .asciiz "31 "
file:    .asciiz   "test.txt"

.text     

.globl __start           

__start:

    li $v0, 4           
    la $a0, question  
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0 $v0
    li $t1 0

Loop:
    blt $t0 $t1 exit
    addi $t1 $t1 1
    jal open_file
    jal fill_file
    jal close_file
    j Loop

open_file:
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, file
    li $a1, 1
    li $a2, 0
    syscall  
    jr $ra

fill_file:
    move $a0, $v0  
    li $v0, 15 
    la   $a1, mynumber
    li   $a2, 3   
    syscall 
    jr $ra

close_file:
    li $v0, 16  
    syscall
    jr $ra

exit:
    li $v0, 10
```

Does somebody have a solution for my problem? Would appreciate ! (Sorry for my english, not a native speaker)

Comment: `open_file` and `close_file` should not be called in the loop.